# Having a nightmare making a JButton Visible

Tags: java

I'm having a problem were a can't make any of the created buttons visible in my frame.

I am trying to create a Frame with 2 layouts the top part is a blank layout and the bottom layout will have three buttons.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.*;


public class Game_Initiliasation extends JFrame {

    int Time;
    int Difficulty;

    JPanel TopPanel;
    JPanel BottomPanel;

    Game_Initiliasation(){
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(300, 300);
        this.setVisible(true);

        TopPanel = new JPanel();
        BottomPanel = new JPanel();

        TopPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(TopPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(BottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JButton Easy = new JButton("Easy");
        JButton Medium = new JButton("Medium");
        JButton Difficult = new JButton("Difficult");

        /*Easy.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                   actionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });*/ 

        Easy.setVisible(true);

        BottomPanel.add(Easy);
        BottomPanel.add(Medium);
        BottomPanel.add(Difficult);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce! I can see all three buttons!

Answer (score 0):

`this.add(BottomPanel);` // Add this line, you will be able to see the buttons

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.*;


public class Game_Initiliasation extends JFrame {

int Time;
int Difficulty;

JPanel TopPanel;
JPanel BottomPanel;

Game_Initiliasation(){
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setSize(300, 300);
    this.setVisible(true);

    TopPanel = new JPanel();
    BottomPanel = new JPanel();

    TopPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(TopPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(BottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    JButton Easy = new JButton("Easy");
    JButton Medium = new JButton("Medium");
    JButton Difficult = new JButton("Difficult");

    /*Easy.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
               actionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });*/ 

    Easy.setVisible(true);

    BottomPanel.add(Easy);
    BottomPanel.add(Medium);
    BottomPanel.add(Difficult);
    this.add(BottomPanel); // Add this line, you will be able to see the buttons

}
}
```